# How to create authentication from scratch in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication

I am trying to make a note application in rails 4 and I really do not want to use devise or any any other user authentication system because I would really just like to code it my self. The only problem I have found is that there aren't any good tutorials out there. The [tutorials that I have found](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQJtlvlNunw) do not teach you how to really do user authentication because you just stay on the so called home page the whole time. So I was wondering if anybody had any ideas or examples of user authentication methods from scratch?

Thanks I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sitepoint has a tutorial, which is old and based on rails 3 so you'll have to adjust for the differences.  http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/ & http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-ii/ -- Have you tried that one?  Also, if you're looking to restrict access once a user has logged in, consider Pundit which lets you write policies for access to different controller actions based on roles.

Comment: I have tried those tutorials but they are to old.

Comment: While old, in order to be Rails 4 compatible there are only 3 real things that need to change.  #1 The routes you add should be stated `get 'signup', to: 'users#new'` or add a `via` to the matcher line:: #2 You'll need to add strong parameters to your controller, but if you use scaffolding to generate them strong params will be there, #3 You should rename `before_filter` in the controllers to `before_actions` as it is the new syntax and possibly a 4th because I didn't get too deep, read up on the validations to make sure they're Rails 4 friendly.  The rest works fine.

Comment: Ok, I will try that out

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it.

You have no idea of the number of ways that you can accidentally leave yourself open to serious compromise.

You are not as smart as the hundreds of developers that have been working for years on devise (none of us are).

Have a look at the [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) for a short list of the ways that people can use your app that you probably never even considered.

If you want to play around and have a go to see how it's done, then sure play... but when you come to actually securing a real app... Just Use Devise.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a personal learning exercise for then there is no better way than to google for information. Plenty of tutorials available. These tutorials don't need to be about Ruby (or Rails). Basic principles are identical regardless of implementation language.

Learn by example via examining existing code. You can find a number of existing auth systems here. Look at their code.
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication

If you are planning to use your own authentication I would discourage you from doing so. The auth problem may seem simple at first, but there are a number of challenges and landmines that await you: sessions, sensitive data storage/transmission, cookie-handling, etc, etc. These are just a scratch at the surface.

Answer (score 0):

The link @miler350 is a great place to start however with Rails 4, ActionModel now has `has_secure_password` that takes care of managing the password hash, you just need `password_digest` field in your table and enable the `bcrypt` gem in your gemfile (don't forget to run `bundle install`). Check out the APIDoc http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods/has_secure_password.

As for authenticating a user I use the `before_action` helper methods in the controllers that I want to protect. For example on my `UserController` I have `before_action :require_login` that references

```
def require_login
  unless current_user
    flash[:error] = MessageBox.alert("You must be logged in to view this")
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

This assumes that you have a helper method in your `ApplicationController`

```
def current_user
  begin
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  rescue
    session[:user_id] = nil
  end
end
helper_method :current_user
```