# Rails 5 application: form and api authentication tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Are there any good tutorial to create an auth system from scraths with form and api authentication?

I found a lot of tutorial but unfortunately they implement only form based or only api based authentication.

But I would like to build a form and api based.
Because for the SEO the server side rendering is important so I can create a registration and login form too. But API based important for a mobile app application.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources, that you might find useful. I have used the first one frequently in the past.

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch
- https://gist.github.com/thebucknerlife/10090014
- https://rubyplus.com/articles/4171-Authentication-from-Scratch-in-Rails-5
- https://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/
- [How to create authentication from scratch in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322482/how-to-create-authentication-from-scratch-in-rails-4)

I hope this gives you some inspiration.